# How do you politely refer to a group of people with the pronoun you?

Tags: politeness, pronouns

Specifically, if a teacher said "I've finished grading **your** tests.", adressing the students, would he use あなた? I've seen it been said a couple times that あなた isn't that polite, so would the teacher use it to refer to his students? Or would he use another word?

Comment: Related [Is it offensive to say あなた?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2727) [Is あなた considered rude?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58799)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases, including a teacher talking to students, using あなた sounds cold, rather than non-polite. (Using あなた **towards** parents or teachers is considered impolite.)

A teacher can use あなたがた to students, e.g. when s/he is scolding them for some bad behavior. But in a case like the one in question, I suppose the most natural would be みなさん (or less politely and more friendlily みんな).

Using みなさん as polite plural *you* works broadly (e.g. in a working environment, to colleagues), but as mentioned above, whether it's ok to use あなた would be ultimately a case-by-case matter.

---

For the particular sentence, not using a pronoun at all may be even more natural: テストの採点が終わりました. *Who* did the grading *whose* tests is just obvious and can/should be omitted.

Comment: Are there teachers that use 君 (君たち) towards students?

Comment: @Kaskade Yes. I forgot to mention it. Probably it is less cold, but sounds kind of pretentious. It may sound ok, like when giving a message to graduating students, but most of the time みんな is the most common if a pronoun(-ish) is ever used.