# Is the sentence, "あなたはこれを望んでいた。" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, verbs, sentence, nouns, subjects

I am a beginner in learning japanese and I've seen many different takes on grammar and where to place verbs, subjects, etc. I know it's a subject-object-verb language and I want to be sure I have the correct order. The sentence is supposed to translate to 'you wanted this' because I am making an album. I also have heard that 'anata' and 'kimi' are considered rude in certain situations and wanted to know if I should get rid of it here.

Comment: Your sentence is *grammatically* perfect, but being grammatical doesn't necessarily mean it's natural. Unfortunately, it's very hard to suggest a revised version without more context. A natural version will depend on who you are, when and how this sentence is used, and what are you trying to present by saying "you wanted this".

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, I see no grammatical faults here. You should try to gain a general familiarity with は and understand that it is [*not* a grammatical subject marker, but a topic marker](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/22), even if it is often natural to use は rather than が to mark what would be a subject in the English translation. SOV is the *most common* word order for Japanese, but it is not strictly necessary, as grammatical subjects, direct objects and indirect objects are explicitly marked using が・を・に.

Regarding あなた・きみ you should read [Is it offensive to say あなた?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2727) and [In actual Japanese society, how often are second-person pronouns used?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4040). For something like this I would not mention the "you" at all, as the context clearly implies it. I probably wouldn't mention the "this", either, frankly.

For an album title, I could imagine something like 望んでいたところ（だ）working (see e.g. [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23738) previous Q&A for ところ). In present tense, simple 望むところ [is a recorded idiom](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9C%9B%E3%82%80%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D). But that's assuming that 望む has the nuance you want; it's a less commonly used word (though not rare either) than 欲しい for example.

Comment: 望むところだ usually means "That's what **I** want/expect", especially when it's used without context.